# Extracting parametric equations from STEP file

Tags: python, cad

I would like to read a `STEP` file generated from a `CAD` software and extract the equations that define geometry.

`SolidWorks` has a similar functionality that recognizes geometric features form generic `CAD` formats such as `IGES` or `STEP`.

Is there a library in `python` or `C++` which allows me to do this?

Comment: You should probably add links to the specification of such files and/or also provide examples of content that should be parsed. This will make the question easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aocxchange](https://pypi.org/project/aocxchange/):

> The aoc-xchange project provides a Python package named aocxchange to
>   read and write from/to IGES, **STEP**, BREP, and STL files using
>   PythonOCC.

You can install it using `pip install aocxchange`

Here is a list of dependencies

1. OCC: Install it using `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/dlr-sc pythonocc-core` or the wheels from [here](http://www.pythonocc.org/download/)
2. aocutils: Install it using `pip install aocutils –upgrade`
3. wx: Install it using `pip install -U wxPython`